# Reading exact number of bytes from c# socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, network-programming

I am using C# sockets (asynchronous mode) and need to read exact number of bytes from the stream to parse the message correctly.  As messages in our system, are very long, seems like socket.EndRead operation returns less bytes than was requested in socket.BeginRead. Any chance to make c# socket mark operation completed only when the exact number of bytes is read??? Is uing NetworkStream is the way ???\

```
IAsyncRes ar = socket.BeginRead(1Mb byte message)
ar.Handle.Wait() // --> will signal ONLY when 1Mb us read !!!!
socket.EndRead()
```

UPD:

I have solved it with c# iterators. (The thread which runs the irator loop and responsible for doing MoveNext is not shown here)

```
protected IEnumerator<IAsyncResult> EnumReceiveExact(byte[] array)
        {


            int offset = 0;

            while (offset < array.Length)
            {
                SocketError err = SocketError.Success;
                IAsyncResult ar = _socket.BeginReceive(array, offset, array.Length - offset, SocketFlags.None, out err, null, null);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:err:{1}", this, err);
                if (err != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    _socket.Close();
                    throw new Exception("Error " + err);
                }

                yield return ar;
                while (!ar.IsCompleted)
                {
                    yield return ar;
                }

                offset += _socket.EndReceive(ar, out err);
                if (err != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    _socket.Close();
                    throw new Exception("Error " + err);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: On calling `socket.EndRead()` it will return the number of bytes available to read.

Comment: I know but I don't want the complication of reading the message in chunks, is there some wrapper that already do it.

Comment: You shouldn't have to read it in chunks? If your client sends 1024 bytes, you "should" receive 1024 bytes in one go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.endread(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Good call with the enumerators, although I hope that your outer code isn't just calling WaitOne on the asyncresults as this would block the running thread.

If you like that style of async coding check out Wintellect AsyncEnumerator on NuGet - it uses iterators too, makes the code very resource efficient and adds easier ways to handle cancellation and exceptions while makings sure APM end methods all get called.

I've previously addressed the exact read problem by:

1) Adding a length prefix to data sent on the socket
2) Defining a helper class that works on a Socket with the following methods:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginRead(AsyncCallback callback)
// Calculate whether to read length header or remaining payload bytes
// Issue socket recieve and return its IAsyncResult

public MemoryStream EndRead(IAsyncResult result)
// Process socket read, if payload read completely return as a memorystream
// If length header has been recieved make sure buffer is big enough
// If 0 bytes recieved, throw SocketException(10057) as conn is closed

public IAsyncResult BeginSend(AsyncCallback callback, MemoryStream data)
// Issue sends for the length header or payload (data.GetBuffer()) on the first call

public Boolean EndSend(IAsyncResult result)
// Process bytes sent, return true if payload sent completely.
// If 0 bytes sent, throw SocketException(10057)
```

So it still needs to be called in a loop but looks like a normal async operation, e.g. called via asyncenumerator (without cancellation checks and exception handling):

```
do
{
    socketHelper.BeginSend(ae.End(1, ar => socketHelper.EndSend(ar)), sendData);
    yield return 1;
    doneSend = socketHelper.EndSend(ae.DequeueAsyncResult());
} 
while (!doneSend);
```

Comment: The outer loop is quite complicated as it manages the reading from multiple client. It receives the handles from each iterator and waits till one of them signaled then it calls MoveNext on proper iterator

Comment: Ok, so assuming your outer loop waits on multiple asyncresult handles with a short timeout, it would stil be slightly more efficient to use callbacks on the async operations - saves blocking the outer thread.